# Increase title spacing stretchability using titlesec with compact

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I have a two-column document that uses the `titlesec` package with the `compact` option. This mostly produces the spacing that I like, but it doesn't give enough stretchability above the section titles which leads to underfull vboxes and spaces between paragraphs. It is especially noticeable in pages that have full-width floats and only one column of text has a heading (e.g., `\paragraph`).

Is there any easy way to increase the stretchability without just guessing values for `\titlespacing`?

Minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\beforetitleunit=1in % lockstep's suggestion (more or less)
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{B}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{C}
\lipsum[3]
\paragraph{D}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does an explicit `\titlespacing{\section}{big stretchy}{big stretchy}` not work? (with appropriate values substituted for "big stretchy")

Comment: @Seamus: It most likely would, but then I'd have to figure out what the default spacing actually and then modify that. That's what I'm trying to avoid. In the end, it may be what I have to do.

Comment: The last page of titlesec manual gives you the defaults...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into `titlesec.sty`, the following code lines seem to define a "building block" for the spacing before and after headings (the actual spacing is determined by applying a multiplier):

```
\newskip\beforetitleunit
\beforetitleunit=1ex\@plus.3ex\@minus.06ex
\newskip\aftertitleunit
\aftertitleunit=1ex\@plus.1ex
```

So try to double the stretchability before headings by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\beforetitleunit=1ex\@plus.6ex\@minus.12ex
\makeatother
```

EDIT: It seems that one must add `\titlespacing` in order to implement the changes to `\beforetitleunit`. The following should work and produce "compact" spacing with double stretchability:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\beforetitleunit=1ex\@plus.6ex\@minus.12ex
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Ba}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get any change by changing that value. See my edit where I added a ridiculous `\beforetitleunit` value to no effect.