# Remove spacing above section in titlesec

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I'm writing a document optimized for mobile usage, and as such I want to conserve my space. The spacing that `titlesec` adds to sections, subsections, etc. is getting somewhat annoying. Is there a (simple) method to remove this? My desire is to just change the look of the title while retaining all LaTeX default spacing, etc.

The `sectsty` package doesn't add any spacing and works great, but I'd like to make use of some of `titlesec`'s features.

I've looked at the following questions and they don't seem to fix my problem:

- [Titlesec: remove space after empty margin section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19200/titlesec-remove-space-after-empty-margin-section)
- [Space above chapter with titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70156/space-above-chapter-with-titlesec)
- [Increase title spacing stretchability using titlesec with compact](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10652/increase-title-spacing-stretchability-using-titlesec-with-compact)
- [Vertical space before section title with titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40436/vertical-space-before-section-title-with-titlesec)
- [Change whitespace above and below a section heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/change-whitespace-above-and-below-a-section-heading)

Please close this if I've overlooked something in the solutions above.

[image: MWE result]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=5mm, paper=a6paper, showframe=true}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*\section{\Large}
\titleformat*\subsection{\large}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section*{Using titlesec}
\subsection*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Note: Remove the three `titlesec` lines to obtain the LaTeX default result.

Comment: This is a great question. Sadly enough, [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)'s formatting is not immediately setup for this kind of thing. Instead, and often very typically, you have to specify *all* of the options in order to change just one thing, without even knowing the defaults of the other. That's the advantage of providing a key-value driven input rather than a full argument-based macro (as `titlesec` does). What's needed here is something like `titleseckv` (doesn't exist) that does everything `titlesec` does, but allows for a `key-value interface with LaTeX defaults otherwise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### UPDATED ANSWER

Do `\usepackage[nostruts]{titlesec}`, which will remove the struts like my answer below did.

The feature was added with version 2.11, released 2019-07-16.

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

The package `titlesec` adds `\strut` in some places. In your case you have to defeat this behavior in three places:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=5mm, paper=a6paper, showframe=true}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttl@select}{\strut}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\strut}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\strut}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\titleformat*\section{\Large}
\titleformat*\subsection{\large}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section*{Using titlesec}
\subsection*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The macros involved are `\ttl@select` and `\ttlh@hang` (in the second one `\strut` appears twice. If other styles are selected it may be necessary to patch `\ttlh@display` or `\ttlh@runin`.

Comment: I believe you can add the option ```\usepackage[nostruts]{titlesec}``` to get rid of the struts altogether.

Comment: @ChristopherCreveling The `nostruts` option got added in 2019. Thanks for the pointer.