# Remove whitespace above section title with image formatted with leftmargin

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to remove the whitespace above a title that is formatted with `leftmargin` and that also has an image as part of it. The problem is very similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79232/), but the solution there does not work for me and it is not using `leftmargin`. There are a variety of other similar questions, but none that I can find with solutions to this particular situation.

When I remove the `leftmargin` formatting the space disappears.

My code is as follows. I would welcome any feedback as to whether there is a better way of achieving the same result (with a wide left margin).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,titlesec,lipsum}
\usepackage[vmargin=0.8cm,hmargin={8.3cm,0.8cm},showframe]{geometry}

% Unrelated: how do you include parameters to commands in \titleformat
\newcommand{\includerotate}[1]{\includegraphics[angle=180,origin=c]{#1}}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\huge}
{}
{0em}                         
{}
[\hspace{-7.5cm}\includerotate{3_lines.pdf}\\]

\titlespacing{\section}
{0cm}{0pt}{7.5cm}

\begin{document}
\section{service overview}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following document. The whitespace that I am trying to remove is between the top margin and the coloured line. Here is a link to [3_lines.pdf](http://files.andybev.com/3_lines.pdf) if you want to compile the code.

[image: example document]

Comment: Impossible to compile your code: `3_lines.pdf not found`.

Comment: @Bernard - okay, I've edited the question and added a link to that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacing comes from the `\huge` in the format argument - it causes an ordinary strut to be inserted before the title is set.  Instead you can use the "before code" argument of `\titleformat` to set the font size and also to place your graphic rule.  I would also suggest that the title is placed in a narrow column raggedright, rather than in a zero width column, with overfull boxes:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,titlesec}
\usepackage[vmargin=0.8cm,hmargin={8.3cm,0.8cm},showframe]{geometry}

\newcommand{\includerotate}[1]{\includegraphics[angle=180,origin=c,viewport=0
12 550 12]{#1}}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{}
{}
{0em}                         
{\rlap{\includerotate{3_lines.pdf}}\endgraf\vspace{-15pt}\filright\huge}
[\strut]
\titlespacing{\section}
{3cm}{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}{4.5cm}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text
\usepackage[latin]{babel} %with correct hyphenation

\begin{document}
\section{service overview}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{other details and material}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

The before prints the rule, in a box that has zero width via `\rlap`.  It then starts a new paragraph, `\par` will not work here, but `\endgraf` is sufficient.  The paragraph is set with `titlesec`s version of `\raggedright`, namely `\filright`, and the `\huge` size is chosen.  The spacing has been changed so the title is set in a column `3cm` wide, and vertical spacing has been added before the title.

Answer (score 2):

My solution consists in considering your coloured rule as a label for the section title, rather than something you add after the section title has been written With the optional arguments of `\raisebox`, you can make LaTeX believe it has no height,no width. So I don't have to include, rotate, &c. any graphics file; the rule is drawn, when the section happens on top of page,just under the top limit of the test area.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[vmargin=0.8cm,hmargin={8.3cm,0.8cm},reversemarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\huge}
{\raisebox{0.575\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\color{HotPink4}\rule{7cm}{3pt}\hspace{14.25pt}\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}}}
{0em}
{#1}
%[\hspace{-7.5cm}\includerotate{3_lines.pdf}\\]
%[\includegraphics{3_lines.pdf}\\]%
\titlespacing{\section}
{0cm}{1.5\baselineskip}{7.5cm}

\begin{document}
\section{service overview}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{service overview 2}
\lipsum[11-15]
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

To answer your subsidiary question: you can very simply use one parameter with \titleformat, which is the section title, if you load titlesec with the `explicit` option. But maybe, you would like to pass other parameters?

Comment: Thanks for this - it works well. The only disadvantage for me is that I am using the same styling for a TOC list, which caused problems as the title of the TOC has no label and therefore didn't display the line. However, I did end up drawing my own line (with shading) and used the raisebox idea to move it into place.