# How can I use titlesec to put a tcolorbox around a section title?

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox, titlesec

I'd like to redefine `\section` to produce something like the following: (requiring package `tcolorbox`)

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
  1. \hspace*{\fill} Title of the Section \hspace*{\fill}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image: the desired format of title]
I assumed I could use the `titlesec` package to do so. I tried doing the following:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]% It's not clear to me why, but any other format except [display] breaks!
    {}{}{0em}%
    {\begin{tcolorbox}\thesection.\hspace*{\fill}}% 'before' code.
    [\hspace*{\fill}\end{tcolorbox}]% 'after' code.
```

The compiler accepts this, but not in the way that I expected it to. `\section{Title of the Section}` produces the following:[image: an image of a faulty title, with incorrect spacing]

I know that `titlesec` does provide a boxed title option, but it is not in the format that I would like to use. In particular I would prefer for the label to also be in the box, and I would like the control over the box that `tcolorbox` provides me.

I thought perhaps I could define the contents of this section title box in the `titlesec` regime, then perhaps define `\edef\oldsection\section` and redefine `\section` as I like, but it's unclear to me how I might pass along the arguments that `\section` takes.

TL;DR I'd like to put `\section` titles inside a `\tcolorbox` as in the first example, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Instead of just posting code fragments, edit your question to include a small compilable example that people can play with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use load the `tcolorbox` packge with the `explicit` option, which allows you to use `#1` as placeholder for the section title in the defintion of the `\section` command. Also, I think the `block` format is better suited here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {}{}{0em}
    {\begin{tcolorbox}
        \thesection. \hspace*{\fill} #1 \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\section{Title of the Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To make this work even for starred `\section` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {}{}{0em}
    {\begin{tcolorbox}
        \thesection. \hspace*{\fill} #1 \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{tcolorbox}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {}{}{0em}
    {\begin{tcolorbox}
        \hspace*{\fill} #1 \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Title of the Section}

\section{Title of the Section}

\section*{Title of the Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As has been pointed out in the comments, this solution does not work nicely with longer titles. Since you are using the `tcolorbox` package already, you could enhance your box a bit to make it work for longer titles as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\NewTColorBox{tcsectionbox}{ o }{%
  enhanced,
  halign=center,
  left=\IfValueTF{#1}{10mm}{4mm},
  right=4mm,
  top=3mm,
  bottom=3mm,
  boxsep=0mm,
  overlay={
    \IfValueT{#1}{
        \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=4mm, inner ysep=3mm] 
        at (interior.north west) {#1};
    }
  }
}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {}{}{0em}
    {\begin{tcsectionbox}[\thesection.]
        #1
    \end{tcsectionbox}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {}{}{0em}
    {\begin{tcsectionbox}
        #1
    \end{tcsectionbox}}

\begin{document}

\section{A ridiculously long section title that is only used to show that even long titles are working fine}

\section*{A ridiculously long section title that is only used to show that even long titles are working fine}

\section{A short title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. May I add, how can I adjust this to account for the label-free `\section*{...}` command?

Comment: @Anton See my edit. For extensions of this, maybe have a look at the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)

Comment: +1 but for long titles the title doesn't wrap in the centre. I would instead wrap the `#1` as `\begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}\centering #1\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, you are right. I was pretty much focused on solving the OP's issue.

Comment: That's a lot of code for a `minipage` :) (But fair enough to use proper `tcolorbox` methods.)

Comment: Using the `nostruts` option with titlesec removes some unnecessary spacing that titlesec adds here, as I have learned. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79232/remove-spacing-above-section-in-titlesec).